# What is the computational complexity of the empirical variogram?

Tags: r, spatial, geostatistics, variogram

If we use the method of moments estimator:

$2\hat{\gamma}(h) = \frac{1}{| N(h) |} \sum_{N(h)} (Z(s_i) - Z(s_j))^2$

What is the computational complexity?

My initial assumption was that it would be $O(n)$, but after testing some values I find that it is $O(n^2)$.

I am curious to know if there is a more theoretical way to show this result.

Comment: Are you trying to program this out yourself?

Comment: No, I am using some of the R packages such as gstat and geoR, just curious from a theoretical perspective

Comment: Since the definition compares each value with each other, as written it's obviously $O(n^2)$.  Moreover, there are as many as $O(n^2)$ distinct possible values of $h$ (even in just one dimension).  There really doesn't seem to be anything to show beyond these trivialities.

Comment: Thank you for another comment on one of my questions whuber, I see the reasoning now